# Splitting Cell based on "AND" to multiple columns in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for the way where we should be able to read each row of the Python data frame and split the string of each cell into multiple columns based on some separator like 'AND'.

-Actual Data Frame having columns "seg_1" and "seg_2":

```
index   seg_1                       seg_2
1       None                        id='clean' AND cid>= 1 
2       id != Android' AND day=3    None
```

-Expected Data frame after split based on "AND" :

```
index   seg_1            seg_2  seg_3       seg_4
1       None             None   id='clean'  cid>= 1 
2       id != Android'   day=3  None         None
```

While split, i dont want to specify the Column Name because the column name is dynamic in my case

i am able to do on specifying the Column name :

```
df.seg_1.str.split('AND',expand=True)
df.seg_2.str.split('AND',expand=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: "the Column Name because the column name is dynamic in my case" - what do you mean? How can you split a column if you do not know which column to split?

Comment: is it possible to parameterise  the Column of the data frame ?  How we can achieve using signle commnd of the below code to split :   df.seg_1.str.split('AND',expand=True)
df.seg_2.str.split('AND',expand=True)     i dont want to specify here seg_1 and seg_2

Comment: Do not use `df.seg_1...`, use `df['seg_1']...`. `"seq_1"` is just a string, you can specify it at run time.

Comment: @DyZ : Is there way to apply the split on all the columns of the data frame ? Column numbers can vary from 0 to n where  value of "n"  is not fixed.